# Proving a Trigonometrical Identity: $2\sin2x\cos6x=\sin8x-\sin4x$

Tags: trigonometry

How can i prove
$$2\sin2x\cos6x=\sin(8 x)-\sin(4 x)$$

As per this identity $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$ but how to proceed from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:you can use the well-known [prosthaphaeresis formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) $$\sin x \cos y=\frac{\sin(x+y) - \sin(y-x)}{2}$$
and get $$2\sin2x\cos6x=2\frac{\sin(8x) - \sin(4x)}{2}=\sin(8 x)-\sin(4 x)$$

Comment: Why are you writing same answer, I just wonder it.

Comment: oh, sorry ... I didn't noticed yours ..

Comment: ok, no problem :)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys i never knew about prosthaphaeresis formulas :)

Comment: they are very strange, but helpful as well in case of problems like that one... ;)

Comment: @Foga, The formula in the first line is http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Comment: which are a generalization of prosthaphaeresis formulas (multiplication instead of addition/subtraction) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** use this identity;
$$sin (A) cos (B) = 1/2  (sin (A + B) + sin (A - B) )$$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to start by using your product-to-sum formulas.
http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html
So, for example, on the RHS,  sin(8x) - sin(4x) = sin(6x+2x) - sin(6x-2x)
on the LHS, letting a = 2x and b = 6x, you use the identity for sin(a)cos(b).
(If you haven't had these formulas, you can derive them easily enough with your angle addition formulas.)
The rest should now be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Write $8x=6x+2x$ and $4x=6x-2x$ and expand.